# QBXML Sales Receipt parsing Error

Tags: qbxml

I'm trying to submit the following QBXML Sales Receipt via "SDK Test Plus 3", and i'm getting an error.

"-2147220480  QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<?qbxml version="7.0"?> 
<QBXML> 
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"> 
      <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="0"> 
         <SalesReceiptAdd> 
            <CustomerRef> 
               <FullName>Test-Sales</FullName> 
            </CustomerRef>
        <ClassRef>
        <FullName>FUpscale</FullName> 
        </ClassRef>
            <TxnDate>2013-04-09</TxnDate> 
            <RefNumber>12</RefNumber> 
            <BillAddress> 
               <Addr1>amazon</Addr1> 
               <Addr2></Addr2> 
               <City></City> 
               <PostalCode></PostalCode> 
               <Country></Country> 
            </BillAddress> 
            <PaymentMethodRef> 
               <FullName></FullName>          
            </PaymentMethodRef> 
            <Memo>Test</Memo> 
            <IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted> 
            <SalesReceiptLineAdd> 
               <ItemRef> 
                  <FullName>AFANG-BK</FullName>          
               </ItemRef>
    <InventorySiteRef>
               <FullName>Roosevelt</FullName>
          </InventorySiteRef>
               <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
               <Rate>1.00</Rate> 
            </SalesReceiptLineAdd> 
         </SalesReceiptAdd> 
      </SalesReceiptAddRq> 
   </QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

---

Win XP
QB Enterprise 13.0 R5

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to upgrade the QBXML version to 12.0